# C++ initialize keys only in std::map

Tags: c++, class, stdmap

I'm looking for a way to initialize only first values in std::map and then initialize the second ones according to the keys. here is my code:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Student
{
public:

    Student(
        double Score_Maths,
        double Score_Eng,
        double Score_Chem,
        double Score_Bio,
        double Score_His
        );
    ~Student();


private:

    std::string Surname;
    std::map<std::string, double> Subject_Scores = { {"Maths"}, {"English"}, {"Chemistry"}, {"Biology"}, {"History"} };

};
```

What I'm trying to do is, to have those keys in class already and then initialize the values using constructor, but of course it shows error when initializing map like that, any help?

Comment: You have to initialize your map like this: std::map <std::string, double> x { 
  { "foo", 1 }, 
  { "bar", 2 } 
};

Comment: instead of just adding keys without values (which isn't legal), add default values to it, then replace them in the constructor with real values.

Comment: You should be able to give defaults for each value: `std::map<std::string, double> Subject_Scores = { {"Maths", 0.0}, {"English", 0.0}, {"Chemistry", 0.0}, {"Biology", 0.0}, {"History", 0.0} };`

Comment: Is it in any way relevant that the code is in a class? Does the code work outside? Also don't forget a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt while this code could *technically* be slightly MORE minimal, I would say this is a pretty good MCVE already.

Comment: so it's impossible without using some pre-assigned values?

Comment: @Nick yes. You can not assign a key without a value or vice-versa

Comment: Technically if you make the value an `optional<double>` it can actually not have a value, rather than just having a magic "invalid" value. But this seems like a lot of complexity without much payoff.

Comment: @Zinki thanks, but it is kinda heartbreaking to hear that. But my motto is - If you don't like the provided, make yours. Hope that in future I'll be able to make some container like what I wanted std::map to be like.

Comment: Seems like you want the ctor default parameter values.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot create something that you do not understand how it suppose to work

Comment: @Nick What would you expect to find in the map if you look up e.g. the "Maths" key when no value was set for that key? Null? 0.0? NaN? Should it throw an error?

Comment: You can't look up, because it doesn't compile, but if you mean what I said about creating a container, it should throw a runtime error

Comment: @Nick then [`std::optional<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) is exactly the type for you! You can `Subject_Scores["Maths"].value()` and get a `std::exception` if nothing is there

Comment: Note that by declaring `Student::Student(double, double, double, double, double)` you have suppressed the default `Student::Student()`, so there is no need for the in-class initialiser

Comment: I beg to differ, @Zinki. The code is neither minimal nor complete, so it's also not verifyable. Remember, a goal of an MCVE is to place focus on the relevant parts and weed out problems that come from losing that focus. BTW: Call me a nitpicker, but "more minimal" is like "more greatest" and I don't know what you mean with "technically".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Whether you consider this code "reduced enough" is a matter of opinion I guess (it's not the *shortest* possible version, but it's close enough imo). It IS, however, complete and verifiable. The problem the OP describes can be reproduced without any changes to it. What makes you think it's not complete/verifiable? The fact that it won't compile is exactly the point, because that is the problem OP has.

Answer (score 5):

> initialize the values using constructor

You can do both in the constructor directly:

https://godbolt.org/g/hWhcxu

```
class Student
{
public:

    Student(
        double Score_Maths,
        double Score_Eng,
        double Score_Chem,
        double Score_Bio,
        double Score_His
        )
        :
        Subject_Scores({ {"Maths", Score_Maths},
                         {"English", Score_Eng},
                         {"Chemistry", Score_Chem},
                         {"Biology", Score_Bio},
                         {"History", Score_His} })
    {
    }
    ~Student();

private:
    std::map<std::string, double> Subject_Scores;
}
```

This still ensures that your map is valid and initialized for the entire class lifetime.

Comment: That's probably what I will do, because c++ doesn't seem to have what I was searching for.

Comment: I am thinking how about passing a map itself to the constructor for scalability. What if the set of subjects change? Will we go on and keep on changing the class. Design?

Comment: @SauravSahu Design-wise I think this is appropriate. You can even add more constructors with different curricula without issues without having to change e.g. a simple printout function. It's not great in terms of scalability, but neither is passing a fixed set of scores to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a (static) function to do that:

```
 std::map<std::string, double> Student::createMap( const std::vector<std::string> &v )
 {
     std::map<std::string, double> r;
     for( const auto &key : v ) r[ key ];
     return r;
 }
```

then in your class:

```
     std::map<std::string, double> Subject_Scores = createMap( { "Maths", "English", "Chemistry", "Biology", "History" } );
```

Comment: +1 for the syntax look-alikeness to what I wanted to do, but still, It assigns 0.0 to the values, which I don't want to happen. But it seems my votes aren't counted.

Comment: @Nick why dont you want that to happen? The thing is: If you want a container that contains only keys and no values then it isnt a map.

Comment: @user463035818 I already wrote about that in my other comments

Comment: You cannot create object of type `double` without any value, that is not possible. If you do not need any value, do not create a key for that or use different data structure.

Comment: @Nick what other comments?

Comment: quoting my other comment - " @Zinki thanks, but it is kinda heartbreaking to hear that. But my motto is - If you don't like the provided, make yours. Hope that in future I'll be able to make some container like what I wanted std::map to be like. "

Comment: To hear what? When you use map and do not want any value - do not insert that key, it is that simple. Looks like you want something you do not understand.

Comment: @Nick I read that comment but it doesnt say why. Btw you can easily write a wrapper for a map that lets you initialize it by passing the keys only, but the map you'd get would still have the values initialized (either default or something else). Also there exists what you want if you use a `optional<double>` as value, however, how useful that is is questionable

Comment: smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)